# Ceiling brick texture is distorted

Tags: materials, uv, texture-coordinates

I'm triyng to scale a brick texture for a ceiling.

It seems that the texture is stretched so I tried to fix it with the mapping Node, but that doesn't fix the problem. I also tried to change the UV and the mesh, but I can't make the bricks come up.

[image]

The roof texture is stretched, but the floor texture is fine.

Here is what Im triyng to achieve:

[image]

> [Here is the .blend file](https://pasteall.org/media/2/4/247221db4a559ac00c6282423191fce9.blend)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You UV map is distorted.
Simply unwrap your roof again and it will work.

1. **Apply scale and rotation** of your roof (*Object > Apply > Rotation & Scale*)
2. Go *UV > Smart UV Project > Conformal*
3. Use *Mapping node* to scale and rotate the texture

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jachym you are the boss... Im a big noob, I hard understand how to work with the uv mapping

Comment: Glad to be of help :). If you get stuck somewhere, feel free to ask more questions.

Comment: wow, you are a good man, thanks a lot jachym if you come to barcelona you have a free tour

Comment: Thanks, greetings from Prague :).